# Schema.org 'potentialAction' for hotel reservation

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I'm a little bit confused. Using Schema.org, what is `potentialAction` for `Hotel` type?

```json
"potentialAction":{
    "@type":"ReserveAction",
    "target":{
    "@type":"EntryPoint",
    "urlTemplate":"https://www.example.com/booking-engine",
    "actionPlatform":[
        "http://schema.org/DesktopWebPlatform",
        "http://schema.org/IOSPlatform",
        "http://schema.org/AndroidPlatform"
    ],
    "inLanguage": ["it_IT", "en-US", "en-UK" , "de-DE", "ru-RU"]
},
"result":{
    "@type":"LodgingReservation",
    "name":"Book Now"
}
```

Where is this supposed to be showed or used? How can I translate that "Book now" for other languages? Should I replicate the `result` key?

Comment: I don’t really understand what your primary question is. Do you try to understand this specific JSON-LD, or do you want to know why one would use `potentialAction`, or do you want to know how? -- The translation question is clear, but it seems to me that it’s not related to your other question(s).

Comment: How this affect SEO? How Google use it (e.g. rich snippet or what else)?

Comment: Here https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.minioffice.lv%2F is one example, where can see `potentialAction`. But i also would like to understand what means `potentialAction` (what it does).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (based on your example):

```
  "potentialAction":
    {
    "@type":"ReserveAction",
    "result":
    {
    "@type":"LodgingReservation",
    "name":"Prenota",
    "alternateName":["Book now", "Buch", "Réservez"]
    },
    "target":
    {
    "@type":"EntryPoint",
    "urlTemplate":"https://www.example.com/booking-engine",
    "actionPlatform":
    [
    "http://schema.org/DesktopWebPlatform", " http://schema.org/IOSPlatform", " http://schema.org/AndroidPlatform"
    ],
    "inLanguage":
    [
    {
    "@type":"Language",
    "name":"Italiano",
    "alternateName":"it"
    },
    {
    "@type":"Language",
    "name":"English",
    "alternateName":"en"
    },
    {
    "@type":"Language",
    "name":"Deutsch",
    "alternateName":"de"
    },
    {
    "@type":"Language",
    "name":"Russian",
    "alternateName":"ru_RU"
    }
    ]
    }
    }
```

Use it in your script type="application/ld+json" (please, note this is not a complete script). Google (and others) will use it to understand the content of your page and increase the chances to show your page in serps and snippets. I used another way to specify available languages. If you are not using Asp.Net Resources to switch languages, use "alternateName" to list all language reservation action Names, as recommended.
PotentialAction is what someone can do, such as a "SearchAction".
If you already solved your problem, share with us the solution working for you.
This one I tested on Google Testing Tool for Structured Data and it's working.